# How to show "new item" form in a pop up in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to show new form in a pop up window when the user clicks on the `new item` of `SharePoint 2013 List` ?

Refer the below image for the same.

[image: New Item Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this step. Please mark answer this if it is helpfull to you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to

**List settings** --> **Advanced Settings**

Then click **Yes** in **Launch forms in a dialog?**

[image]